# Zebra 2824 printer is printing ZPL commands as text

Tags: java, swing, zebra-printers

I am writing a Java swing app that print a label to mark a product. 
The printer is a Zebra 2824 Plus, and I'm sending ZPL2 commands over the serial port to print the label I want. However, the commands I sent to the printer are printed as text.

This is the code that connects to the printer and sends the label to be printed.

```
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(app, 2000);
outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
String command = "^XA^FO30,30^A0N,30,30^FDqwerty^FS^FO30,70^A0N,30,30^FDqwerty^FS^XZ";
byte[] data;
data = command.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
dataOutputStream.write(data);

dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
serialPort.close();
```

the result is 
`^XA^FO30,30^A0N,30,30^FDqwerty^FS^FO30,70^A0N,30,30^FDqwerty^FS^XZ`

I'm running it on Windows and the connection is through a Serial port.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is the printer connected to the printer?  Serial?  USB?  What kind of printer is it?  What platform are you running on? You might also benefit from reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm running it on windows and the connection is thru a Serial port.

Comment: Perhaps you need to send extra commands to configure the printer in the correct mode. Maybe you already know, but Zebra used to have a SDK, at least for BB and Android. You might be able to reuse some classes from those libs.

Comment: Thanks, but still didn't go

Answer (score 0):

I don't know java well, but the symptoms you describe seem to indicate that the print job is going through the windows drivers instead of directly to the port. (windows can write to a zebra printer).

In VB I would do a filecopy command from a temp text file with the raw ZLP in it and copy that textfile to that port. (in other words I save the ZPL string to a file and then copy that file to the serial port). I'm sure Java can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The printer may be in line-print mode.  In this mode, ZPL commands (and most other commands) are not processed and instead printed directly to the label.  This mode is useful for generating receipts on the fly that may have variable length.

You can put the printer back into ZPL mode by sending the following command to it:

! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"

[Notice that the command MUST end with a new line character, or "\r\n" in Java]

Source: [ZPL Manual page 709](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl_manual.pdf)

Comment: my printer just prints the command as text even when I send it the command to set it to ZPL ! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"

Answer (score 0):

Answer and solution found [here](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7296).

- Connect the printer to the desktop via USB cable.  Open up Zebra Setup Utilities, select your printer, and hit "Open Communication with Printer".
- Enter any of the following commands, followed by the enter key (to insert a carriage return), and then press the "Send to Printer" button on top.

  - ! U1 setvar "device.languages" "ZPL"
  - ! U1 setvar "device.languages" "line_print"

**Note:** When enabling the ZPL language support you will have to calibrate the printer using the ~JC command. (The printer media must be loaded and ready to feed labels before calibrating.)

Use the communications window to send the following after the ZPL calibration and save parameters command.

```
    ~jc^xa^jus^xz
```

The printer will feed labels and calibrate to the label length saving the values.